# MongoDB Node.js driver: How to find out if findOneAndUpdate actually found a document and updated it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to use the `Collection` method [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.6/classes/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) of MongoDB's native Node.js driver to find and update a document in one single operation.

I then need to perform some logic that depends on if the document was successfully found and updated or not.

According to the driver's documentation, `findOneAndUpdate` returns a [`ModifyResult`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.6/interfaces/ModifyResult.html). This has the field `ok` with expected values being either `0` or `1`. So this seems to be promising.

However, what *meaning* does `ok = 0` or `ok = 1` have?

- Is `ok = 0` "I looked for documents according to your filter, but found none, so did not update any"?
- Is `ok = 0` "I failed to look for documents because of an error"?
- Is `ok = 0` "I looked for documents according to your filter and found one but failed to update it?
- Is `ok = 1` "I looked for documents according to your filter, and may or may not have found some - and if I found one, I did update it"?
- Is `ok = 1` "I looked for documents according to your filter, and definitely found one and updated it"?

Comment: You can use `FindOneAndUpdateOptions` - `returnDocument` and `projection` options are useful to get the updated document for verification.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @prasad_. While the question remains open, I implemented the following logic: `if(ok && result.value != null) { /* assume that something was found and successfully updated */ }` This seems to work, based on very very few tests. So do not necessarily put too much trust into this - a clear answer to my question would still be very helpful.

Comment: This is an old question but I still struggle to find a solution and the documentation is horrendous or completely non-existing. Did you manage to find a proper solution?

Comment: See my last comment: My use case only required to proceed if something was found AND successfully updated. So I relied on the condition specified in the comment. I have not found out anything beyond that.